# How to select 2 same columns differently from same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a total beginner in SQL and I can't to this :

I have one table with cars and oldCars which are linked via another field.
The field name in the table is listing all cars name and the same field is also listing oldCars name.
How can I make a SQL to see 2 columns( 1 column with the car name, 1 column with the oldCar name from the same field for related Car-OldCar.
The car and the oldCar are linked via 2 fields on the table (ModelA, ModelB).

So for example, if I want to see the oldCar of car 'mercedes', 
I do this :

```
select name from table X
where ModelA IN (select ModelB from table X where name in ('mercedes'));
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some example of your database?

Comment: Can you please put some sample data and schema of the table to understand the problem better

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple SELECT statement with JOINS.

```
Select a.Name as NewCarName, b.Name as OldCarName
FROM ModelA AS a -- new car table
INNER JOIN ModelB AS b -- old car table
ON A.SameField = b.SameField
WHERE a.Name = 'Mercedes'
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the fields are not the same in the table.
Except for field name, that is why i need to make a select in statement to find related OldCar

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your table `car` to have this shape:

```
| id   | name            | old_name_id |
| ---- | --------------- | ----------- |
| 1    | 'Peugeot'       | null        |
| 2    | 'Mercedes'      | null        |
| 3    | 'Mercedes Benz' | 2           |
```

First I would imagine a request that returns 2 columns: `name` and `old_name`:

```sql
SELECT c.name, old_c.name 
FROM car c
JOIN car old_c ON (c.id = old_c.old_name_id)
```

which should return this:

```sql
| c.name          | old_c.name      |
| --------------- | --------------- |
| 'Peugeot'       | null            | -- not sure
| 'Mercedes'      | 'Mercedes Benz' |
| 'Mercedes Benz' | null            | -- not sure
```

this will return all the cars having an old name (not sure if it will show the entries with `null`, but I think yes because it is a `JOIN` and not a `LEFT JOIN`.

Now, if you want to isolate and get only the entry for `'Mercedes'` for example, do it like this:

```sql
SELECT c.name, old_c.name 
FROM car c
JOIN car old_c ON (c.id = old_c.old_name_id)
WHERE c.name = 'Mercedes'
```

and you will have this result:

```
| c.name     | old_c.name      |
| ---------- | --------------- |
| 'Mercedes' | 'Mercedes Benz' |
```